# Skip numbers while doing a For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have 80 div with unique ids that counts from 0 to 80,e.g. grid0, grid1, grid2 and so on.

I want to use a for loop to iterate over all of them and hide them,but I want to skip some grids. What should I do?

This an inaccurate example of what I mean:

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) (skip numbers 51,60,69,78) {
  $("grid" + i).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a check with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf),

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {
    if ([51, 60, 69, 78].indexOf(i) === -1) {
        $("grid" + i).hide();
    }
}
```

or with ES6 and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {
    if (![51, 60, 69, 78].includes(i)) {
        $("grid" + i).hide();
    }
}
```

BTW, your string building method does not work, you need to put plus sign and index outside of the string.

```
$("grid" + i).hide();
//^^^^^          string
//       ^       concatination
//         ^     with number
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and correction, I am going to edit it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {
  if (![51,60,69,78].includes(i))
    $("grid" + i).hide();
}
```

Comment: Preferred the `continue` version - reduces nesting if there's a lot to do inside the if.  Some purists don't like it.

Comment: Check compatibility of `.includes` - perhaps not the best option? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the continue JavaScript keyword.

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {

    if(i === 51
    || i === 60
    || i === 69
    || i === 78) {

        continue;

    }

  $("grid+ i").hide();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

> The continue statement "jumps over" one iteration in the loop.

So inside your loop just do an
`if (i == 51) continue`
before the `hide`

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. MDN is far more comprehensive, accurate, up to date and authoritative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Point noted and will definitely do so in future. In this particular case though I think W3Schools is a better resource for those just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Give the elements a class, hide all of them via class and then show the ones you need:

```
<div class="grids" id="grid0"></div>
<div class="grids" id="grid1"></div>
<div class="grids" id="grid2"></div>
...

$("div.grids").hide();
$("#grid51").show();
$("#grid60").show();
```

Comment: Or, conversely, give the class to the ones you don't want to show, but essentially the same.  `$("div.grids:not(.donthide)").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 80; i++){
   if(i !==51 && i !== 60 && i !== 69 && i !== 78){
      $("grid+ i").hide();
   }


}
```